# python return dictionary from function

Tags: python-3.x, function, dictionary, return

I tried a lot however still have a problem with returning dictionaries from a function. I can e.g print d1 and d2 from inside the function but not outside. When I use the following script I get: NameError: name 'd1' is not defined. Thank you for your help!

```
ref = """text a"""

target = """text b"""

def text_to_dict(x):
    # value formatting to list = new_values
    # key formatting to list = keys
    # dict creation from keys and new_values
    if x == ref:
        d1 = dict(zip(keys, new_values))
        return d1
    elif x == target:
        d2 = dict(zip(keys, new_values))
        return d2

text_to_dict(ref)

text_to_dict(target)

print(d1)

print(d2)
```

Answer (score 1):

d1 and d2 are function variables, they are not visible outside the function.

```
dict1 = text_to_dict(ref)

dict2 = text_to_dict(target)

print(dict1)

print(dict2)
```